# Cannot open and read downloaded files

Tags: java, android, file-io, download, urlencode

Hope someone can help me.

I tried few ways of downloading files from URL but everything gives the same result - the file is there, including the file extension, but I can't open and read the file. The last way I use is

```
else if (!myFile.exists()) { // if file not exist
                    try {
                        String downloadPath = download_file_path+fileName;
                        downloadPath = URLEncoder.encode(downloadPath, "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20");
                        new DefaultHttpClient().execute(new HttpGet(downloadPath))
                                .getEntity().writeTo(
                                new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), fileName))
                        );
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

I tried every solutions available in SO but can't solve the problem. Please help.

Comment: Define 'can't open and read the file'.

Comment: @EJP not sure if this is what you mean. the downloaded file is in the directory, as an unknown file type. But it has the file extension. For example, blahblah.pdf. since it is unknown file type, I can't open it using pdf reader. but if I connect my phone to my laptop, I can open the file by using Open With option.

Comment: @EJP i open it manually, from file manager